# Condition Based Monitoring | CBM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, signal-processing, feature-extraction, fault

Machine Learning (ML) can do two things from Vibration/ Acoustic Signal for Condition Based Monitoring (CBM):
1 . Feature Extraction (FT) and 
2 . Classification

But if we look through the research/process, then why signal processing techniques are used for pre-processing and ML for rest of the part; I mean classification?
We can use only ML for all of these. But I have seen the merging model of the two techniques: conventional signal processing approach and ML.

I want to know the specific reason for that. Why researchers use these two; they could do with ML only; but they use both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so. However, the task becomes more complicated.
FFT for example transforms the input space into a more meaningful representation. If you have rotating equipment you would expect that the spectrum is mainly on the frequency of rotation. However, if there is a problem the spectrum changes. This can often be detected by for example SVMS.

If you don't do the FFT but only give the raw signal, SVMs have a hard time.

Nevertheless, i've seen recent practical examples using Deep Convolutional Networks which have learned to predict problems on raw vibration data. The disadvantage is, however, that you do need more data. More data is not a problem in general, but if you take for example a wind turbine more failure data is obviously -- or hopefully ;-) -- a problem.
The other thing is that the ConvNet learned the FFT all by itself. But why not use prior knowledge if you have that.....